# ElasticSearch range in sum aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a new user of elasticsearch and I would like make a range on sum aggregation.

So, I have :

```
{
  "query": {},
  "aggs": {
     "group_by_trainset" : {
        "terms": {
           "field": "trainset",
           "order": { "sum_compteur": "desc" }
         },
         "aggs": {
           "sum_compteur": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "compteur"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And I have a 10 first results.

I want a pagination or it's not possible to aggs on elasticsearch. I try to return the next 10 results.

So, I want display the 10 results that are lower than the lowest value of the "sum_compteur" of the first 10 results and I don't know how.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you please explain your que. in brief? what you want to achieve ? @Clement

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you add an example stating what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every hit you'll get same Aggregations given input parameters are not changes. 
If you want to specify size in aggregation counts you can do is:

```
"aggs": {
       "sum_compteur": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "compteur",
            "size" : 1000,
            "order" : { "_count" : "asc" }
           }
        }
     }
```

Where *1000 is the no of aggregation values you need.
You can also sort the results using "order". And later add pagination in the output array..